# change colour of individual bar in bar graph using c3js

Tags: jquery, c3.js

How to change the color of individual bar in a bar graph.

```
    var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 50]

        ],
        type: 'bar',
        colors: {
            data1: '#ff0000'
        },
        color: function (color, d) {

            return d.id && d.id === 'data1' ? d3.rgb(color).darker(d.value / 120) : color;
        }
    }
});
```

Here, all bars which have value greater than 45 should be green in color and those below 45 should be red in color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make `data.colors.data1` a function, like so

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 50]

        ],
        type: 'bar',
        colors: {
            data1: function(d) {
                return (d.value >= 45) ? '#00ff00': '#ff0000';
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
       show: false
    },
    // take care of color in tooltip
    tooltip: {
        contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
            color = function() {
                return (d[0].value >= 45) ? '#00ff00' : '#ff0000';
            };
            return chart.internal.getTooltipContent.call(this, d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color)
        }
    }
});
```

I assumed 45 to be green by the way.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vc1Lq1um/

Comment: Might be too old of a thread, but this doesn't show the correct color in the pop-up tooltip. Is there a way around that without rewriting the whole tooltip via http://c3js.org/reference.html#tooltip-contents?

Comment: Updated answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In case this is helpful for someone, this [codepen](https://codepen.io/stefita/pen/RPWLWr) by Stefka Todorov shows how to change colours according to 'category'. Helpful for anyone trying to change colours of one ***or more bars***, and simpler than using boolean.

(Sharing this because I came here looking for how to change colours of C3 bars, and could not change colours for multiple bars using the earlier suggested method.)

```
 var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#uv-div',
            size: {
                height: 150
            },
            bar: {
                width: 40
            },
            padding: {
                left: 60
            },
            color: {
                pattern: ['#FABF62', '#ACB6DD']
            },
            data: {
                x: 'x',
                columns:
                    [
                  ['x', 'Category1', 'Category2'],
                  ['value', 300, 400]
                  ],

                type: 'bar',

                color: function(inColor, data) {
                    var colors = ['#FABF62', '#ACB6DD'];
                    if(data.index !== undefined) {
                        return colors[data.index];
                    }

                    return inColor;
                }
            },
            axis: {
                rotated: true,
                x: {
                    type: 'category'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                grouped: false
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            }
        });
```